# How to convert intermittent string elements in a json to arrays using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have an IAM policy with Statement.Action elements that are both arrays and strings depending on the number of entries within them.

For example there are some such as

```
    {
        "Sid": "Name1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "logs:GetLogEvents",
            "ecs:DeleteCluster",
            "logs:PutRetentionPolicy",
            "logs:PutLogEvents",
            "s3:GetReplicationConfiguration"
        ],
       "Resource": "arn:aws:cognito-idp:*:*:userpool/*",
        "Condition": {
            "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                "aws:ResourceTag/VendorType": "ABC"
            }
        }
    },
```

and also Statement.Action elements such as

```
    {
        "Sid": "Name2",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "cognito-identity:DeleteIdentityPool",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:cognito-identity:*:*:identitypool/*",
        "Condition": {
            "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                "aws:ResourceTag/VendorType": "ABC"
            }
        }
    },
```

Essentially i want to be able to sort the elements under Action.

However since some of the Action items are string and not arrays when running the following command

```
jq '.Statement[].Action|=(. // [] | sort)' file.json
```

I get an error

```
jq: error (at file.json:277): string ("cognito-id...) cannot be sorted, as it is not an array
```

This is resolved if all Statement[].Action elements were in arrays and some weren't strings.

So if i change the above erroring entry in the json to the following it solved the problem.

```
    {
        "Sid": "Name2",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "cognito-identity:DeleteIdentityPool"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:cognito-identity:*:*:identitypool/*",
        "Condition": {
            "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                "aws:ResourceTag/VendorType": "ABC"
            }
        }
    },
```

what combination of jq commands could i use to have entries where Statement[].Action is a string and not an array be converted to an array such as the above so i can then run sort on elements inside it.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume the objects with "Action" keys are in an array.  Then you could sort the "Action" values that are arrays by writing:

```
map( .Action |= (if type=="array" then sort else . end) )
```

Or if you want to ensure that `.Action` is always array-valued:

```
map( .Action |= (if type=="array" then sort else [.] end) )
```

### .Statement

So you'll probably want to write something like:

```
jq '.Statement[].Action |= (if type == "array" then sort else . end)' file.json
```